# Basic events are not triggered in the unit tests written with react-testing-library for the drag-and-drop feature developed using @dnd-kit

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, drag-and-drop, react-testing-library, dnd-kit

I've been working on developing a drag-and-drop feature for a specific use case and attempted to write unit tests to cover potential scenarios. However, I encountered an issue where the events available within @dnd-kit/core (onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragOver, onDragEnd) were not being triggered while executing drag events in the unit tests.

I experimented with various approaches to simulate dragging one element and dropping it onto another. I tried using fireEvents available from @testing-library/react. None of those methods proved effective for me.

Method 1:

```
fireEvent.dragStart(firstItem)
fireEvent.dragEnter(lastItem);
fireEvent.dragOver(lastItem);
fireEvent.drop(lastItem);
fireEvent.dragEnd(firstItem);
```

Method 2:

```
fireEvent.pointerDown(firstItem);
fireEvent.pointerMove(firstItem, { clientX: 100, clientY: 100 });
fireEvent.pointerUp(firstItem);
```

I'm seeking a solution or guidance on how to effectively test drag-and-drop features using react-testing-library.

Any suggestions or help are greatly welcomed and appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Please elaborate "None of those methods proved effective for me". It is not clear what problem you are trying to solve. It is not clear what criteria you would like to test.

Comment: Thanks for checking out the problem I mentioned. I'm attempting to write unit tests to cover basic scenarios, like triggering specific functions after dragging one element onto another. However, I'm facing an issue: when I use fireEvents from @testing-library/react to trigger drag and drop events, the callback functions linked to the @dnd-kit/core context don't get invoked.

This issue is hindering my ability to write proper unit tests for the drag and drop feature. I hope this explanation clears up the problem. If not, please feel free to ask for more clarification.

Comment: tag [unit-testing] exists. Maybe add it, to improve findability? You can use up to five tags. Also any useful information you just posted in comment, please rather add it directly into your question.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61755034/12846804 - https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/1540 - https://reactjsnews.com/testing-drag-and-drop-components-in-react-js

Comment: Appreciate the tips! I've included all the relevant tags for the post. Unfortunately, the suggested links didn't quite fit my scenario, as the drag and drop library they referenced differs from the one I'm using. I experimented with the concepts they provided, but no luck so far. My guess is that the library I'm using not based on the HTML5 drag and drop API, which could be the reason why the suggested solutions aren't working for my case. Thanks again for your guidance!